# screen to screen command

Tags: android, xml, button, onclick, screen

Hi am new to android and have spent over 10 hours looking for this answer but i cant seem to find and understand it. I am at the main xml page. I am trying to create a button that goes to another page. I need the easiest and simplest way to do this. Can anyody please help me? Heres my code for my main xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: You could have saved time by going to the link @OvidiuLatcu posted. Always go to developer.android.com and if you don't find your answer come here and search some questions, if still nothing, post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp" 
    android:text="Button" />
```

Go to your activity Initialize your button

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
// Register listener to button btn
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

            // your action

            Intent newActivityIntent= new Intent(currentActivity.this, NewClass.class);
            startActivity(newActivityIntent);       
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This process is documented on the website concerning buttons. Google search Android Button

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
 android:text="Button"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:onClick"insertMethodNameHere"
 />
```

This will call the method you define in the `onClick` tag, then start a new activity or update the view. Whatever you need to do

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it different...

You can instantiate a [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) in your Activity:

```
private Button button;
```

Inside the `onCreate(Bundle bundle)` method you find your button, as defined at this Activity XML, which is the one you used `setContentView(R.layout.yourxml);`:

`button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);`

Then you use an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

Inside the onClick method, you instantiate an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

`Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToGo.class);`

CurrentActivity = the one you are, and ActivityToGo the one you want to load.

`startActivity();`

Read the basics on Android [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Use a switch on v.getId() if you have multiple clickable views.
        // Since there's just one button, ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class;
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn **How to switch between Activities/Screens in Android**, you can find [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/) a  well explained tutorial for beginners